# Same domain names internal and external issue

Tags: domain, active-directory, domain-controller, domain-name, domain-registration

**UPDATE 1:**

Basically, from a computer outside the network, I can access the website by typing into the browser address bar, either of the following, which is how it should be:

```
http://www.companyname.com
http://companyname.com
```

However, from within the company network, we can only access the external website by typing in

```
http://www.companyname.com
```

It will not work if I type

```
http://companyname.com
```

**ORIGINAL QUESITON:**

Our internal network has the same domain name as our external website, lets say it's companyname.com for both the website and for our internal network.

This is causing problems because I am unable to access the companyname.com website from within the network.  I have to use a computer from outside the network to see the website.

Is there a way around this issue, ideally without having to change the internal or external domain names?

Comment: look at my explanation in my answer.  That's what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a split DNS

http://www.isaserver.org/tutorials/You_Need_to_Create_a_Split_DNS.html

A hacky way to fix it would be to put an A record in your DNS that points to the IP of the website.  (So www.yourcompanyname.com resolves to the website address)

The best way to fix it would be a split DNS. And that about sums up my knowledge of it. You might get lucky and have someone else expound further on it.

What you're seeing is (based on my experience) *.yourcompanyname.com resolving to the SOA in DNS, which is why you're not able to get to the website internally.  Put in an explicit A record for www and that should fix it.

Comment: Where does this new A record go?  In our internal DNS server, or the external DNS server?

Comment: You're having the problem internally, so your internal DNS.

Comment: I should also say that you're not going to be able to do anything else but what you have already.  If you can resolve it internally by going to www.yourcompanyname.com that's about the best you can hope for with your current situation.

Comment: Even with the split dns solution?

Comment: well, no that would fix it.  sorry, I meant that comment to regard the A record fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is little confused, so your description of the problem is not detailed enough to suggest a solution. And, in fact, if you clear up your wording, you may discover that a solution will then suggest itself to you.

Networks don't have domain names. Do you mean that a resource on your internal network has the same domain name as your website. And do you mean that it has a different host name within the same domain, maybe www.companyname.com for the website and intranet.companyname.com for the internal resource, or are they the exact same host name? Finally, do you need to be able to access both the internal and external resources at the same time from the same computer?

Comment: Really sorry about that.  I don't know anything about networking, I am a programmer, trying to make my life a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to your external website as `companyname.com`, do you actually mean `www.companyname.com`?

If so, the solution is simple. Just create an A record in your DNS that points to the external IP address for your website.

If you are referencing your external website by `companyname.com`, then you can't redirect that name internally, as that DNS entry is required to point where it currently does for your AD to function. You only option is to change your web site to use `www.companyname.com`.

This is one of the very reasons why I *always* use `companyname.local` internally, and `companyname.com` externally.

Comment: Please see update 1 in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

In your description of the problem you have not indicated if this is as Windows or Linux environment, if its Windows than in your DNS server you can add a new Host A record using your websites Public IP address.

Edit - Brians answer

Comment: The tags specify Windows

Comment: Yes, our internal network in Windows based, and our external website is Linux based.